# How create image 2d from 1d array (setting density)

Tags: gnuplot

I have big output space for example table = 1..900 000 000
and would create a image 2d. My data is simple:
table[x]

How produce image 2d to show this points

0 1 2 3 ....

this is normal image. But trouble is i need tiled for example 4x4

---

small data example

**00 01** 02 03 04 05 06 07

**08 09** 10 11 12 13 14 15  --->  if data is 1,29

16 17 18 19 **20 21** 22 23

24 25 26 27 **28 29** 30 31

....

i need one pixel 2x2 = if my point is in some 0,1,9,8 (left corner 2x2) i get one pixel. second pixel example 20,21,28,29 is colored if exist one x in my data (20 or 21 or 28 or 29)

i need setting density my image, i accept script to manipulate my data solution too

data: 9, 28 produce image with 4xn with 2 pixel colored (0,0) left top corner and (2,1) bolded.

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to do. From here, you seem to just randomly pick the block 18,19,25,26. We actually have no idea what your logic is and what you need to accomplish.

Comment: @DanSp. Do You know what is 'or'?  I need image with colored pixel if data is in rectangle. I write bolded pixel and eexample add data. I write data, information before and after. What I can write more?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that probably the most robust approach would be to preprocess your data with an external tool in order to produce a matrix which you could then [plot](http://www.gnuplotting.org/interpolation-of-heat-maps/) with the `with image` plotting style.

In order to do this, you need to transform the data points into `row,col` pairs which denote the position of the corresponding point in the 2D matrix. To be more specific, let's assume that we want to construct a `P x P` 2D matrix, where each cell (pixel) is `c x c` large. For the example in your question, `P = 4` and `c = 2`. Now, for a particular value `x`, in order to determine the `row`, we can just divide (integer division) `x` by the number of numbers in a single row of the final 2D matrix, i.e., `row = x / (c*c * P)`, since there are `P` cells with `c * c` elements each. As for the column, we can first normalize `x` into the interval `0 - c*P`, i.e., numbers of the first row of the cells in the first row of the 2D matrix, and then check to which group of `c` elements it belongs, i.e., `col = (x % (c*P)) / c`.

Now, if the number of data points is not too large, one can process it directly in Gnuplot and plot each "pixel" as a separate rectangle object:

```
fName = 'test.dat' #data file

P = 4 #how many pixels per row/column
c = 2 #each pixel is c * c

#check how many points we have
stat fName nooutput
N = STATS_records

#load the data into an array
array points[N]
idx = 1
stat fName u (points[idx]=$1, idx=idx+1, $1) nooutput

unset key
set size square
set xr [0:P]
set yr [P:0] #reverse y-axis

set x2tics 0,1,P out nomirror
unset xtics
set ytics 0,1,P out nomirror

#construct a rectangle for each data point
do for [i=1:N] {
  x = int(points[i])

  row = (x / (c*c*P))
  col = (x % (c*P)) / c

  set object 100+i rect from col,row to col+1,row+1 fc rgb "dark-red" fillstyle solid 1.0
}

#generate the plot (the rectangles are all we wanted to show,
#so just plot "nothing")
plot 1/0
```

For data values of `1, 29`, this would produce:
[image]